# EF Code First - Recreate only table, not recreate database

Tags: ef-code-first

I have my app and db on hosting. I can not delete database by myself, so I want to if model changes recreate only tables and database will not touch.

I see that somebody use sql command to delete table and create it new, but it is possible to just disable database delete and Code first script just delete table and create new ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably have to create a custom DbInitializer, which knows how to drop any existing objects in your database.  Instead, have you considered moving the EF Code First Migrations, now available in EF 4.3?  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) for a walkthough.

Comment: Woow, I was waiting for this feature from beginning of EF CF ;) Great!